# How to submit a form when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I want to submit a form only when a check box is checked, or display "Please check the check box", is there any way to do that? Can any one guide me ?

thanks

```
<form  name="myForm" action="mailsent.php" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" class="chk_row" name="chk1[]"" value=" '.$rows["id"].'"/>

<input type="submit" value=""  style="margin:7px 26px -27px 1424px;background-image: url(/image/exporttt.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;cursor:pointer;" >

</form>
```

Edited code:

```
<form  name="myForm" action="mailsent.php" method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_row" id="chk1" name="chk1[]"" value=" '.$rows["id"].'"/>

    <input type="submit" value=""  style="margin:7px 26px -27px 1424px;background-image: url(/image/exporttt.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;cursor:pointer;" >

    </form>

<script>

$('form').submit(function(){
  if(!$('#chk1').is(':checked')){
      alert("Please Check ");
      return false;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should first try it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [submitting a form when a checkbox is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602470/submitting-a-form-when-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: I think your question title is wrong. I read it as the form should be submitted when you click the checkbox.

Comment: no form should submit when i check the checkbox and click the submit button,if i submit the button without checking the checkbox i dont want to submit the form

Comment: is there any possibility to have multiple check box?

Comment: yes i these check boxes in the td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery
You should give your checkbox unique ID

```
$('form').submit(function(){
 var flag=0;
  $('.chk_row').each(function(){
     if(($(this).is(':checked'))){
      flag=1
      return false;
     }
   });
  if(flag==0){
    alert("Please Check Checkbox");
    return false
  }
});
```

Your your_checkboxId is what you give id in your input chekcbox
eg.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="your_checkboxId" name="chk_name" value="some" / >
```

Comment: form should submit when i check the checkbox and click the submit button,if i submit the button without checking the checkbox i dont want to submit the form

Comment: By this code I did not submit your  form pls check, And You have to give unique Id to your checkbox @arok by <input id="uniqu_id" .....

Comment: what i want if i check the check box and click the submit button i want to submit the form,i the check box is not checked i dont want to submit

Comment: check box id should not use like chk1[] , I've changed to chk1 @arok

Comment: but form is not submitting if the check box is checke d

Comment: form is submitting when not checked ? @arok

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48834/discussion-between-arok-and-farhad)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using jquery, give your submit button with id 'submit', and then use this code

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if( $("[name='chk1[]']").is( ':checked')){
      return true;
   } else {
     // your custom code here
      return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#submit").click(function(e)
    {
    if($("#check").is(':checked'))
    {
        $("#form").prop("action","mailsent.php");
    }else
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
```

And you need not specify the action in form tag. `#form` is id of form, `#check` is id of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there is only one checkbox here, and I am selecting it using the class name. You may modify the selector as per the implementation to pick the desired one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.chk_row').change(function(e){
if($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked')
{
$('form[name="myForm"]').submit();
}
});
});
```