# Dynamically add text into body as I click <Select> indexes in coldfusion

Tags: dynamic, coldfusion

On my cold fusion page what I want to do is click one of the options from my `<Select>` statement. After doing so I want to see a richtextbox be dynamically filled with a matching record in my database from the value of the item I clicked. I also want it to do the same for a checkbox, and authors  object.

Each object already has a column in my database, what is left is to add this dynamic feature to fill in my data for editing a post.

My code looks like this:

```
<!--- Query --->
<cfquery name="Posts" datasource="Postings">
Select *
from BlogPosts
</cfquery>

<!--- Fill Listbox --->
<cfselect name="LoopPosts"  size="12">
<cfoutput query="Posts"><option value="#PostID#">
#PostTitle#</option></cfoutput>
</cfselect>

<!--- Secondary Query --->
<cfquery name="PostsQuery" datasource="Postings">
Select *
from BlogPosts
</cfquery>

<!--- Fill  --->
<cftextarea style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;" name="PostBody" id="blog"><cfoutput query="Postquery">#PostBody#</cfoutput></cftextarea>

<input name="ActivePost" type="checkbox" value="<cfoutput query="Postquery">#Active#</cfoutput>">
```

Comment: The data is going to get pulled back via either a get, post, or AJAX. You need to consider which approach you are going to use.

Comment: Ok, if that is the case, how can I trigger a submit just by clicking one of the objects in my list box. Then I will dynamically fill everything. Also could a Bind function somehow grab the value from my <Select> and inserting it into the where of a query statement potentially?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602470/submitting-a-form-when-a-checkbox-is-checked has some examples. (Just ignore the PHP ness)

Comment: Didn't answer the question. I want to click one of the options in my "listbox" to active the click.

Comment: Why, in the name of all that is holy, are you using Access? Access is not designed to be the back end for web applications. You will hit performance issues. Try something better/cheaper like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: How to submit from a select: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me try to redeem myself with a modified answer:

You can dynamically reapply options to elements using ajax calls to your cfc file (since cfc bind is apparently a no-no) by adding an event listener to the first select field and calling the method in the cfc file via an AJAX get request.  In the success function, you can then update the response to the textarea field.

Every time a selection is made from the select box, the text box will refresh the data with the appropriate query result.

The HTML page could look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms['yourformname'].elements['LoopPosts'].addEventListener('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "yourcfcfilename.cfc?method=GetSelectedPost",
      data: {selectedPost : this.value},
      success: function(response) {
        document.forms['yourformname'].elements['PostBody'].innerHTML = response;
      },
      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the cfc page could look something like this:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Post Functions" output="true">

  <!--- Secondary Query --->
  <cffunction name="GetSelectedPost" access="remote" returntype="String">
    <cfargument name="selectedPost" type="string" required="true">

      <cfquery name="PostsQuery" datasource="Postings">
        SELECT PostBody
        FROM BlogPosts
        WHERE PostID = <cfqueryparam value="ARGUMENTS.selectedPost">
      </cfquery>

      <cfreturn PostsQuery.PostBody>
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Every time a selection is made from the select box, the text box will refresh the data with the appropriate query result.

Comment: I do not recommend using this approach. ColdFusionUI is unreliable at best. Your best bet is to use jQuery AJAX.

Comment: Yea...don't use `cffrom`, `cfselect` or any other CF UI elements. They are more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: Works with the listbox by itself. The cftextarea however says `[object Object]`. Reading what cftextarea supports, it seems that display isn't one of them.

Comment: Changed `WHERE PostID = <cfqueryparam value="ARGUMENTS.selectedPost">` to `#selectedPost#` on the assignment side. Within another `<Select>` I finally have it working, however when using a cftextarea I still receive `[object object]` error.

Comment: Your recent changes cause this message: "The specified remote function GetPosts was not found on the CFC EditPosts."

Comment: Your first answer is technically working after I switched to state the variable #selectedPost# (as shown on the CF documentation http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_a-b_6.html). It is just that any control that isn't a `<select>` shows `[body body]`

Comment: Maybe the return type in the cfc function needs to be changed to string?

Comment: The method works. Found this example on a website that used more than just Select statements. http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/10/18/Ask-a-Jedi-ColdFusion-Ajax-example-of-retrieving-fields-of-data