# Checkbox filter django

Tags: html, django

I'm improving my English, be patient

I'm using django-filter and in some part of my HTML I have this structure

```
{% if viagens.count == 0 %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <h3 class="text-danger">O colocador nao fez nehuma viagem</h3>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="row">
    <form action="" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        # here I want a checkbox that automatically submit the form
    </form>
</div>
{% for viagem in viagens %}
    <p>Placeholder</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I don't have javascript knowledge, I need this with pure HTML and Django

Comment: I need to grab the value of the checkbox and perform a corresponding queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know you can't without JS.

Check this:
[submitting a form when a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602470/submitting-a-form-when-a-checkbox-is-checked)

With pure HTML, you can use:
<input type="submit" value="submit>
or
<button type="submit>Submit