# HTML Assigning the checkbox to the form action already defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the form with action targeted for the specified task. I want to have this form also sent by email. It can be the `:mailto` option or other.
[Mailto on submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626940/mailto-on-submit-button)
[image]

So When I click the Submit form, the form is submitted. However I would like to attach another action to this action, namely I would like to send this filled form to the email by checking the ckeckbox.

So far I saw, that sending the form by checkbox is possible:

[submitting a form when a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602470/submitting-a-form-when-a-checkbox-is-checked)

but the pivot thing here is assigning the other `form action` to my form...

[HTML form with multiple "actions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660734/html-form-with-multiple-actions)

I tried something like this:

```
  <form id="c_form"  action="default_url_when_press_enter" method="get" onsubmit="return validate(this);" target="_blank" >

  ....

  <input type="checkbox" action="mailto:mk@gmail.com" id="cfemail" name="email">
  <input class="btn" action="c_form.html" type="submit" id="cfsubmit" value="Submit form">
```

but it didn't work unfortunately as well as with the code applied below:

```
   document.getElementById("cfsubmit").addEventListener("click", function(){
                                                                
    document.getElementById("c_form").className="submitted";
                                                            });
```

How can I send email along with the form submission when my box is checked?

The full code is available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ptgbvfen/

Comment: None of the DOM elements shown in your sample code have the id `cfsubmit`. Please post a coherent example.

Comment: ok sorry, i forgot to add the link to my full code

Comment: @MKR There is no cfsubmit in your jsfiddle sample either

Comment: Which backend language do you use to handle the data? You can add send email action in your backend code, right after it saves data?

Comment: I use Javascript only.

Comment: @Tschallacka I've fixed the code see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far if I understand your problem correctly, you want to submit the form normally. But if the checkbox is checked you want to perform a `mailto` function as well.

> HTML:

```
<form id="c_form" onsubmit="return validate(this);" target="_self" >

  ....

  <input type="checkbox" id="openmail" name="email">
  <input class="btn" type="button" id="cfsubmit" value="Submit form">
```

> Javascript

```
document.getElementById("cfsubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var check = document.getElementById("opemail"); // Get checkbox element
  var mainForm = document.getElementById("c_form"); // Get form element
  
  if (check.checked == true) { // If checked then fire
    let link=document.createElement("a"); // Creates <a> element in DOM
    link.href = "mailto:mk@gmail.com"; // Adds mailto link to <a>
    link.click(); // Clicks the <a> and open default mail app
    link.remove();
  }
  
  mainForm.submit(); // Submits the form
 });
```

*******************Updated*****************___**

Removed the `action` attribute from `form` element, because you do not need it when you want the form to submit on the current page. Also changed the `target` attribute to `_self` so that it will not open new tab whenever you submit the form.

*******************Updated V2*****************_**

Made `mailto` autofill the email content when `checkbox` checked and `form` is submitted, as requested. If you find it helpful then kindly upvote, and if you are facing more issue then comment down below. Thanks.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rzos1bwt/

> HTML

```
<form id="c_form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div id="Page1">
    <h2 class="property">Property information</h2>
    <fieldset>
      <figure class="property_information">
        <figure class="fig">
          <label>
            <div class="order">A</div>
            <p>Proposed Cable Route<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></p>
          </label>
          <br>
          <select name="proposed_cable_route" id="cf_proposed_cable_route">
            <option value="" disabled selected>-Select your answer-</option>
            <option value="External">External</option>
            <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
            <option value="Combination">PIA</option>
          </select>
        </figure>

        <figure class="fig" id="cf_building_post_2000">
          <label>
            <div class="order">B</div>
            <p>Is the building post 2000?
              <span class="asterisk">&#42;</span>
            </p>
          </label>
          <br>
          <input name="building_post_2000" type="radio" value="Yes" selected>Yes
          <input name="building_post_2000" type="radio" value="No">No
          <br>
        </figure>

        <figure class="fig" id="cfasbestos">
          <label>
            <div class="order">C</div>
            <p>Do you have asbestos report?
              <span class="asterisk">&#42;</span>
            </p>
          </label>
          <br>
          <input name="asbestos_report" type="radio" value="Yes" selected>Yes
          <input name="asbestos_report" type="radio" value="No">No
          <br>
          <h3 class="alert">Please contact your team leader for advice!</h3>
        </figure>
      </figure>

      <figure class="fig">
        <label>
          <div class="order">9</div>
          <p>Surveyor<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></p>
        </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="surveyor" placeholder="Surveyor's name">
        <input type="email" name="surveyor_email" placeholder="Email">
        <br>
      </figure>

      <div class="emailreceipt">
        <input type="checkbox" id="opemail" name="email">
        <label for="opemail">Send me an email receipt of my responses</label>
      </div>

      <input class="btn" type="submit" id="cfsubmit" value="Submit form">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Javascript

```
document.getElementById("cfsubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var check = document.getElementById("opemail"); // Get checkbox element
  var formEl = document.forms.c_form; // Get the form
  var formData = new FormData(formEl); // Creates form object
  
  // Get all form data values
  var cableRoute = formData.get('proposed_cable_route');
  var buildingPost = formData.get('building_post_2000');
  var asbestosReport = formData.get('asbestos_report');
  var surveyorName = formData.get('surveyor');
  var surveyorEmail = formData.get('surveyor_email');
  
  // This will create the subject of form
  var subject = "Submission from " + surveyorName;
  
  // This will create body with filled data
  var body = 'My name is ' + surveyorName + '\n' + 'My email is ' + surveyorEmail + '\n' + 'Proposed Cable Route: ' + cableRoute + '\n' + 'Is the building post 2000: ' + buildingPost + '\n' + 'Do you have asbestos report: ' + asbestosReport;
  
  // Making the mailto link with urlencoding
  var mailTo = "mailto:mk@gmail.com?subject="+encodeURI(subject)+"&body="+encodeURI(body);
  
  if (check.checked == true) { // If checked then fire
    let link=document.createElement("a"); // Creates <a> element in DOM
    link.href = mailTo; // Adds mailto link to <a>
    link.click(); // Clicks the <a> and open default mail app
    link.remove();
  }
  
  //console.log("mailTo => ", mailTo)
  mainForm.submit(); // Submits the form
 });
```

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to submit the form normally, but perform the email as well when checked. Unfortunatyle I see no reaction when action="default_url_when_press_enter". From where does it come from? I saw it in other example and used it but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @MKR I have updated the code. One thing just came to my mind that are you trying to autofill the email when checkbox is checked. Like message content should autofill message field in email app ?

Comment: OK it seems to be fine, but I have 2 questions:
1. Is it possible to make it running by using target_blank?
2. As far as I understand it's going to be an empty email without any content from this form? How can I include the content of the form I have filled in?

Comment: Updated the code, and solved your question number two. While for your question number one you can use 'target= _blank' I would not recommend it but you can use it without any issue.

Comment: You are perfect! I have accepted your answer, because it seem to work!
The last question I have:
What should I do to make the form populated simultaneously when the email is sent?
Once email checkbox is checked then only the mail is populated, but I need uncheck the box if I want to have the form populated.
I have added the mainForm.submit(); within the if (check.checked == true) {} but it didn't woork.
Is there any quick way to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand you clearly. Can you be more descriptive with your question.

Comment: I mean, that the form is not populated when the email is sent. I have to uncheck the box for making the form submitted.

Comment: is all sorted! Thanks a lot for your help :)