# Replace the null record with N/A in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to replace the `null` record with N/A when possible in JavaScript.

I have the form, where some of the questions are reliant on other questions. If, for instance, some of the questions in marked as "yes" then other questions are not required, therefore they're inactive, as per below.

[image]

Next, I've prepared the email form like shown here:

[HTML Assigning the checkbox to the form action already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318300/html-assigning-the-checkbox-to-the-form-action-already-defined)

and everywhere, where I have the unanswered question (while inactive ones) the result shows `null`.

I would like to have `N/A` instead of `null` everywhere, where questions are to be inactive due to selection.

My initial code looks like this:

```
   var surveyFailure = formData.get('h3g_survey_failure_reason');
```

and I tried something like this:

```
var surveyFailure = if 
 formData.get('h3g_survey_failure_reason') = null {
  surveyFailure = "N/A"
 };
```

but it doesn't work, as i get

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'**

Is there any chance to replace the `null` with `N/A`?

Full code is available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/r5kw4f6g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error, the correct code shoud be this:

```js
var data = formData.get('h3g_survey_failure_reason');

var surveyFailure = (data === null) ? "N/A" : data;
```